# How to debug SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR?

Tags: debugging, browser, protocols, spdy

In legacy application *hosted in Amazon AWS* we are getting `SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` for a certain page. This happens in **Google Chrome** and **Opera**, but in Firefox the page loads normally. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY the SPDY implementations in Chromium and Firefox might be a bit different, in **Chromium** the error occurs anyway. The problem is not happening within the same webpage in the local development environment.

After doing some research via Google I did still not find a good answer on how to debug this (from a developers or server administrators perspective). What can I do to identify the source of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be caused by **zlib output compression setting in AWS**. After disabling this setting all worked again. Chances are that the server was *sending invalid content length headers* for some special pages which is not accepted by Chrome and Opera.

There is some discussion about this in the Cloudflare support forums: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-err-spdy-protocol-error/71356

Here is the answer from the Cloudflare community:

> **Error**
>
> Try the suggestions in this Community Tip to help you fix ERR SPDY
>   PROTOCOL ERROR when visiting a site.
>
> **Background**
>
> The Error ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR while visiting a site indicates a
>   network error that is preventing the page from loading. If you’ve
>   restarted your browser, updated Google Chrome, tried in incognito
>   mode, and flushed and renewed your IP, try the Quick Fix Idea below to
>   address the issue.
>
> **Quick Fix Ideas**
>
> 1. If you are not the site owner, contact the site owner and let them know you are having issues accessing their site.
> 2. Short term, change your :orange: to :grey: which would bypass Cloudflare. This is not optimal, but would fix the problem in the
>      short term by taking Cloudflare out of the mix for anything but simple
>      DNS resolution.
> 3. There is a mismatch between the Content-Length header you are sending and the actual content-length.
> 4. Fix your origin response headers. For Apache, review this 18. If you’re using a hosting service, please contact your hosting provider
>      to make this change for you.
> 5. Upgrade to Pro in order to disable http/2.